# what does this string.format piece of code do?

Tags: c#, string.format

I have this piece of code in c#:

```
private static void _constructRow(SqlDataReader reader, system.IO.StreamWriter stwr, bool getColumnName)
{
  for (int i = 0; i < reader.FieldCount; i++)
   stwr.Writeline(String.Format("<td>{0}</td"), getColumnName ? reader.GetName(i) : reader.GetValue(i).ToString()));
}
```

I'm trying to understand what the part that start with "getColumnName ?" and ends with ".ToString()" does. I understood that it is a system.object type, but I have no idea what it specifically does or how it works.
I want that because of this: "reader" had multiple rows in it, and I want to writeline only specific rows.

If anyone can help me on either of those, I'd be grateful.

Comment: This code has a closing parenthesis too many.

Comment: @Konrad's right, this `"<td>{0}</td")` should be `"<td>{0}</td"`

Comment: You are also missing a closing angle bracket in the closing html tag. Should be String.format("<td>{0}</td>", ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function iterates over all columns in the data reader, then for each one:

If `getColumnName` returns true, it outputs the name of the column between the `<td>` tags, otherwise the value of the data.

To de-construct further:

```
reader.GetName(i) - this returns the name of the column

reader.GetValue(i).ToString() - this returns the value of the column as a string

getColumnName - a function the will return true if a column name can be gotten

?: - the conditional operator. If the expression before the ? is true, the expression to the left of the : is used, otherwise the one on the right

String.Format("<td>{0}</td", arg) - this will output "<td>arg</td>" (btw - your code is wrong, the ) should not be just after the first string)
```

Comment: the most detailed answer, and I saw the ) bug as well thanks to this. 
Oded, Cheers and Toda!

Answer (score 3):

This is a [conditional operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691313(VS.71).aspx?ppud=4).  It says if `getColumnName` is true, then use `reader.GetName(i)` otherwise use `reader.GetValue(i).ToString()`

The format is this:

```
ThingToCheck ? UseIfCheckIsTrue : UseIfCheckIsFalse
```

In the code, it looks like `getColumnName` is **true** for the header row, so it's outputting the column name and called again for all other rows using **false**, to output the values.

Answer (score 0):

That is called a conditional operator.

The argument `getColumnName` is evaluated and if true, the first argument after the `?` is returned, if false, the second.

So, if getColumnName==true, you are going to see `<td>NAME</td>` else `<td>Value</td>`

Make sense?

Answer (score 0):

It is like following

```
if (getColumnName == true)
{
    reader.GetName(i); // GetName is string so no need to convert this in string I.E ToString()
}
else
{
    reader.GetValue(i).ToString(); // GetValue returns object so this needs to convert in string using .ToString()
}
```

Because getColumnName  is of bool type so no need to test it like

```
If (getColumnName == true)
```

You can write this as

```
If (getColumnName)
```

**String.Format(string, method)**

And String.Format method replaces items in specified string with given object, this method has two arguments first one is string and second is object.
for example

```
string.Format("Question number {0} is answered by {1} {2}", 11, "Adam", "Yesterday");
```

The out put will be

Question number 11 is answered by Adam Yesterday

As you can see {0} is replaced with 11 and {1} is replaced with Adam and {2} is replaced with Yesterday.

you can read more about this [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fht0f5be.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

this is [ternary operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28(VS.80).aspx), used for adhoc constitution of if else block.